# ELK stack for storing data from multiple devices .conf file

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm creating a statistic `microservice` for my app.

I need to collect information from 5 different clients: `IOs, Android phone, web client and JS client`.

Can anyone help me with `.conf file for logstash?`

I would like to send `json-s directly to logstash`, is it possible? Or do I always need to read logs from file? Which filter do I need to use? How to specify inputs for them?

My ELK stack will be running on amazon ec2 container service, as a `microservice`.

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to send input data to logstash. With current version you can find the list here-https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html

I'm not sure if would be able to help you design how you want to do it but some of the sugeestions i could give are-
1) log these message in a standard way in a file in json format and use the file plugin  (if you want logstash on same machine as where file is stored)
So the input part would look something like

```
  input  {
       file {
      path => ...
      codec =>json
    }
```

2) use kafka plugin. This requires installing kafka and writing a kafka producer program to send your messages to logstash. Messages are sent using a topic you created.
The logstash input would look like-

```
 input {
kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "..."
        topics => ["..."]
        codec => json
    }

 }
```

This might seem complicated but helps remove dependencies and decouple your architecture. You would have to have an understanding of kafka too.

These are just a couple but you could use others if you like based on your requirement.

To differentiate the clients which sends the data, in your json you could have a field called "client" using which you can filter and perform some task.
To filter data based on client field you would have to reference it like- "%{client}"

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Logstash has an http input.  You could set that up to listen, and have your applications PUT data into logstash for processing.

There are also inputs for tcp and udp, and probably others that you could use.

Your applications would have to deal with the case when logstash was busy/unreachable/dead.